# what are the ASO and BSO , what is advantage to use these

Tags: essbase

what are ASO and BSO and difference between aggregated storage and block storage?

when to use aggregated and when to use block storage technique.?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Answers http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26232_01/doc.11122/esb_dbag/frameset.htm?ainaggr.html

Shortly: If you have а very spare cube and do not need update values in cells by users, use ASO

Answer (score 1):

A very fundamental and frequent question which appears in all Essbase interviews is what is the difference between ASO and BSO applications.
Here are few differences between ASO and BSO
Essbase system has two distinct storage options Aggregate Storage Option (ASO) and Block Storage Option (BSO) each one has its own unique significance.

***Characteristics of ASO:***

High dimensionality.

No Calculation scripts.

Only one database can be created under one application.

Mandate to fallow the naming conventions for Application name as Applications names should not be metadata, temp, log, default.

Dynamic time series and Time balance properties are not available.

The dimension build process builds any new member then the data will be erased otherwise the data will be alive.

Only one type of partition available (Transparent)

There is no concept of Sparse and Dense dimensions.

No Boolean attribute tag.

Only store data, never share, label only data storage properties are available.

***Characteristics of BSO:***

Less number of dimensions but shows the business model.

Special functionalities for Accounts and Time dimensions like Dynamic time series, Time balance, Variance reporting.

3 types of partitions Replicated, Transparent, Linked.
Currency conversion is possible.

There is no restriction of the number of databases under one application but performance costs.

Complex calculations can be achieved using calc scripts.

Answer (score 1):

In ASO we can load data at only level 0 where as in BSO we can load data at any level.....

Answer (score -2):

I know BSO a little, so I want to talk about ASO.

ASO(App Store Optimization) is the process of optimizing mobile apps to rank higher in an app store’s search results. The higher your app ranks in an app store’s search results, the more visible it is to potential customers. That increased visibility tends to translate into more traffic to your app’s page in the app store.